# Opening PDF on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I tried to open a pdf file using react-native-pdf-view

my code is :

```
export default class PDFExample extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render(){
    return(
        <PDFView ref={(pdf)=>{this.pdfView = pdf;}}
            src={"./Tizi.pdf"}
            onLoadComplete = {(pageCount)=>{
            this.pdfView.setNativeProps({
            zoom: 1.5
                });
            }}
    style={styles.pdf}/>
            )
    }
}
```

and i got this error :

```
Invariant Violation: Native component for "RNPDFView" does not exist
```

Comment: I think first you need to install and link react-native-PDFView package.Then you can use PDFView component inside your View.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you did not link the library. The steps are usually the following:

1) npm install THE_PACKAGE --save

2) react-native THE_PACKAGE

If the package does not contain any issues it will be linked, otherwise you need to link it manually, or switch to another solution, for example, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-pdf. There you can also find a readme which describes the steps need to be done. It's generic, so you can apply for any package.